# Swift NSFetchRequest group by one attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "shopItem.wishList == %@", currentWishList)
    fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "mainBestPrice", ascending: true)]
    let minPriceExpression = NSExpression(format: "min:(mainBestPrice)")
    let minPriceED = NSExpressionDescription()
    minPriceED.expression = minPriceExpression
    minPriceED.name = "productPrice"
    minPriceED.expressionResultType = .DoubleAttributeType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["shopItem.keyword", "productTitle", minPriceED]
    fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["shopItem.keyword"]
```

I want to group by by one field with `NSFetchRequest`, but always get error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain
>   properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions

that i should use all fields from `propertiesToFetch` in group by. But i don't want do this...

Comment: No way round this.  You've either got to add `productTitle` to the `propertiesToGroupBy`, or remove it from `propertiesToFetch`.  It may be you can get what you want a different way: either with Key value coding collection operators, or an NSFetchedResultsController.  If you edit your post to include details of the entities and relationships (one-many, many-many), I'm sure you'll get some suggestions.

Comment: i really need all fields, can you show please how i can group results maybe after ```fetchRequest``` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` (see the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)).  This is normally used to populate a table view, but can also be used to group the results of a CoreData fetch - the `sectionNameKeyPath` determines the grouping.  The fetch must be sorted in a way that ensures that all items in a group are sorted together.  In your example, you are grouping by `shopItem.keyword`, so you need to specify `shopItem.keyword` as the first sort descriptor.  The second sort descriptor should be `mainBestPrice` (ascending), so that the first item in each group is the item with the lowest `mainBestPrice` for that group.  Hence the configuration for the FRC would look something like this:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "shopItem.wishList == %@", currentWishList)
let keyWordSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "shopItem.keyword", ascending: true)
let priceSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "mainBestPrice", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [keyWordSort, priceSort];
let myFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath:"shopItem.keyword", cacheName:nil)
do {
    try myFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    abort()
}
```

Now, the products with the minimum best price will be the first item in each section, eg. for the first section (i.e. the first `shopItem.keyword`):

```
let firstProduct = myFetchedResultsController.sections![0].objects![0] as! Product
```

or to get an array of them (for all `shopItem.keyword`s),

```
let products = myFetchedResultsController.sections!.map() { $0.objects![0] as! Product}
```

The NSFetchedResultsController will do its best to optimise for memory and speed, though you should take care if you have large volumes.